# How to create nested fields in a schema?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nested, schema, field

Lets say that I have this user schema that has a inventory with multiple slots. How could I nest those slotsimg and slottext fields inside the inventory field?

For example like this:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Inventory: {
    slot1img: {
      type: String,
    },
    slot1text: {
      type: String,
    },
    slot2img: {
      type: String,
    },
    slot2text: {
      type: String,
    },
    slot3img: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
});
```

However if I try it like this it wont show up at all in the database, so how do i do this?

Comment: Schema by itself won't show up in the database, did you save a document?

Comment: @Joe I know that, yes i did. Thanks for your help but i have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#embedded-document-pattern. If anyone else runs in to this problem use the link :)